# Call Child window function from parent window javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On my xyz.aspx page I added a Iframe and set it src to abc.aspx page, when I load xyz page Iframe is alos loaded as well abc.aspx page inside it. I am able to call a function from abc.aspx to xyz.aspx function, the question is how can I call abc.aspx function from my xyz.aspx page?

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope, the following solution will help you:

Parent to iframe:

```
document.getElementById('yourframe').contentWindow.yourFunction();
```

Iframe to parent:

```
parent.yourFunction();
```